# Use sub-report data in main report Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

Good Afternoon,

I am having an issue getting data from a sub-report to my main report.

I have a database that stores information on customer transactions. Inside the transactions, it has different products purchased. If I put all the products purchased records on the main report I get duplicate transaction records for each product. So, therefore, I have found that if I do a subreport with all of the products in the subreport and the transactions in the main report I do not get duplicate transactions.

I want to count each transaction where a certain product was purchased from the sub-report. So for instance, if Transaction 1 contained Product 1 then that would count as 1  but if it didn't contain Product 1 it wouldn't count.

I hope this makes sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is information about that specific product, you could simply add a condition of `{Product_Code} = 1` to the record selection formula.

But your situation is probably more complex. Still, no need for subreport. You can group the report on Transaction_Code (or whatever you need to summarize by. Suppress the detail section. Create a formula like `IF {Product_Code} = 1 Then 1 else 0` and simply SUM it at the desired level of grouping. Show the sum in the Group Footer.  This is known as a Conditional Total. You could get the same result by creating a Running Total with a condition but that approach is less recommended.